# Playing a Waveform Image

Tags: playback, websites, waveform, app

I am looking for a way to play custom waveform image via a phone app or even a website. Basically something just like Skin Motion but something that can be read via a picture.

Does anyone know if something of this sort exists?

https://skinmotion.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called PhonoPaper made by a Russian group. It is essentially a graphical representation of sound that can be read by a camera and specific software. Quite cool, if somewhat novel.

http://warmplace.ru/soft/phonopaper/

There is possibly some way of reading a sonograph image back into sound. Perhaps look into SSTV technology too which is the tech they used to send images from the Moon to Earth from Apollo 11. It basically is the reverse ie stores visual information as a sound.